# redirecting non existed page to home page and example.org to www.example.org in .htaccess with virtual hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I am testing out a few things on Ubuntu apache2. I am able to solve the individual problems but when those are combine it messed up and showing "this webpage has a redirect loop”. Okay..Here is the setup.
My site is www.example.org and subfolder www.example.org/kmc. In subfolder, we have Joomla CMS installed.

In .htaccess file, I did two setup.

1) example.org will be forwarded to www.example.org

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)S http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works.

2) the non-existed page will be forwarded to the home page.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.org
```

It works too.

Now I setup the virtual host in the 000-default.conf file. The reason is I want two different sites on the same server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/kmc
    ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I go to the example.org, the browser shows "This Webpage has a Redirect Loop".

Comment: Is there a page at `http://www.example.org`?

Comment: Yes. Just simple index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `www` rules should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Your rule is missing `www.` in the target URL.